# Unable to run Jersey web service on tomcat

Tags: eclipse, rest, jersey, tomcat7

I have developed a simple rest web service using Jersey 1.17.1 and deployed in Tomcat 7.0.41. However I am getting 404 response (The requested resource is not available) when hitting the service URL. I did find the below statement in tomcat log, not able to figure out why -
com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFO: No provider classes found.

Below is the code I am using :-

```
package com.test.rest.service;
import javax.ws.rs.GET; 
import javax.ws.rs.Path; 
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam; 
import javax.ws.rs.Produces; 
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType; 

@Path("persolazation")
public class PersolazationService { 
@GET       
@Path("/name/{i}") 
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)       
public String userName(@PathParam("i") String i) {       
String name = i; 
return "<User>" + "<Name>" + name + "</Name>" + "</User>"; 
}            
}
```

and web.xml is below :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">   
  <display-name>RESTfulWS</display-name>   
  <servlet>   
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>   
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>   
    <init-param>   
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>   
      <param-value>com.test.rest.service</param-value>   
    </init-param>   
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>   
  </servlet>   
  <servlet-mapping>   
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>   
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>   
  </servlet-mapping>   
</web-app>
```

I am using the following URL to call the service :- http://:8080/RESTfulWS/rest/persolazation/name/Robert .

```
Catalina.out logs are below -
INFO: Deploying web application archive /usr/local/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/RestfulWS.war
Dec 26, 2013 11:56:08 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  com.test.rest.service
Dec 26, 2013 11:56:08 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class com.test.rest.service.PersolazationService
Dec 26, 2013 11:56:08 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFO: No provider classes found.
Dec 26, 2013 11:56:08 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.17.1 02/28/2013 12:47 PM'
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

Please advise.

Thanks,
Deep

Comment: Have you tried with @Path("/persolazation")?

Comment: Works for me. Check also your webapp "Context root". Should be "RESTfulWS" in project properties -> Web project settings. By default, it's the name of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Since the name of your war is RestfulWS.war, by default Tomcat will host your application at `http://localhost:8080/RestfulWS`.  That will be the context root for your web application (assuming you haven't changed your Tomcat port).

If you hit that url and if you have an index.html under src/main/webapp then you would see the contents of index.html.

Next, since you've mapped /rest/* to the Jersey servlet you need to add that to your path.

Then, since you've specified @Path("persolazation") in your PersolazationService class you need to add that to your url as well.

Since you've further mapped your method to @Path("/name/{i}") your url becomes:

`http://localhost:8080/RestfulWS/rest/persolazation/name/Deep`  (or whatever name you want to supply)

Note, although you do have `<display-name>RESTfulWS</display-name>` in your web.xml that will not influence or affect your url or context root.  You will see that name in Tomcat Manager as the name of your web application, but the web app context root will be based off of the name of your war file.

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for your responses. I had used the complete URL as you guys have suggested. Didn't work. The issue was resolved when I changes @Produces in the method from MediaType.TEXT_XML to  "application/xml" or "text/xml". I am using Jersey version 1.17.1.